# Whitebox testing Cyclomatic complexity

Tags: cyclomatic-complexity

I'm trying to learn the cyclomatic complexity, but i'm stuck in this step. How does it gets the sequence value <1, 13, 18, 45, 49> as highlighted below? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFTyU.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It is executed by calling a function `int res = binarySearch(18,sequence);`

It is most likely that the key is set to 18 to show that in this variant we do not find the solution as it is already found.

Comment: but where did he get the value 18? is it just a random number to show us example?

Comment: I changed the answer.

Comment: Does it mean the values in the sequence are random?

Comment: It is input data. Nothing here says where does it come from. And I don't know what is `Cyclomatic complexity`